# The difference between to rebel and to revolt

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference in the following sentences in terms of meaning?

> He urged people to **revolt** against the established government and turn
>   the revolution against the king although he preferred to remain aloof
>   from the actual events.
>
> He urged people to **rebel** against the established government and turn
>   the revolution against the king although he preferred to remain aloof
>   from the actual events.

Answer (score 1):

There is really little difference between the two words; only separated marginally by their definition which is:

> Rebel- A person who refuses allegiance to, resists, or rises in arms
>   against the government or ruler of his or her country.
>
> Revolt- To break away from or rise against constituted authority, as
>   by open rebellion; cast off allegiance or subjection to those in
>   authority; rebel; mutiny:

So, in this context according to the dictionary, **rebel** would be slightly better to use because it is rebelling against the ruler/government of the country.

Answer (score 1):

Practically to rebel and to revolt are synonyms. In rebel you have the Latin word element re- back and bellum war, in revolt you have re- and the word family volvere/volvi/volutum (infinitive, perfect, past participle) and the idea to turn things over/to throw down those who have the power.http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=revolt&searchmode=none